Trying to understand Nest thermostat wiring
I just arrived at my parents' house to discover that as of last week, their Nest thermostats (2, separate A/C, shared furnace) are continuously running out of power and needing to be charged.  According to the Nests themselves, the Rh wire is not connected to anything, which likely explains why they aren't getting as much power as they used to.  I'm trying to figure out what may have gone wrong and whether it's something I can fix myself.
Here's a picture of one - the other appears to be wired the same way.

I've tested the voltages (of this one), and from Rc to Y1 or G I read 24V, but from Rc to W1 I get 54.  From Rh to Y1 or G there's nothing at all, and from Rh to W1 I get the expected 24.  The unattached wire in the middle doesn't do anything.
Any ideas what could be going wrong here?  Or other things I can investigate?  Is this even a valid setup in the first place?

This is the best picture I could get of the furnace end of things.  There's a Y, G, R, and C that are all connected, and a W that's unused.


Does what you describe match how the wires are mounted on the control board at the furnace?

Just to clarify—your parents have two Nests, each controlling an A/C unit+furnace—basically two separate systems?  Do you have a wiring photo at the furnace and/or A/C unit?

@DelphicOracle - Haven't tested the voltage yet, but I've added a picture and description of the control board, as best as I was able to access it.  It doesn't match up particularly well.

@Huesmann - One furnace with two heating zones.  Each zone has a separate A/C and Nest.

Since there is no yellow wire at the Nest, It looks like the wires have been spliced. You will need a signal tracer to find what the spliced wires match to.

@DelphicOracle - It looks kindof washed out in the picture, but the Y1 wire in the Nest is yellow, and the "dirty gray" W1 wire is white.

What is W1 on the Nest connected to on the furnace?

Has anyone done any work on either units?

@DelphicOracle - That is a very good question I don't currently have an answer to.  I'd guess that it's C, just because the furnace has a C connected and the Nest doesn't, but that would mean someone spliced a white wire to a black one somewhere along the way.  I'll try to get a tracer and see if I can get clarity.

@JACK - I just checked.  Apparently, someone was poking around the wiring a few weeks ago, but it was (seemingly) working fine after that until a power outage last week.  So... maybe?

Someone poking around the wiring can often cause wires to be disconnected or at least a lose connection... check them all.

This isn't well documented but if you have a split source system (where the heat and the AC come from different units) then the power and common wire must come from the AC system (on Rc). I ran into this when connecting my AC and Hydronic systems.
Also, your common wire must be connected and I can see in your photo that it isn't.
Rh is 24v line for heat. Rc is 24 volt line for cooling. If they come from the same source then they are the same and you can either connect the two conductors at the source or your thermostat can combine them.
W is the heating signal. This gets connected to Rh by the thermostat when there is a call for heat.
Y is the cooling signal, connected by the thermostat when there is a call for cooling.
G is fan.
C is common. This is the wire used to power your thermostat. If this is not connected sometimes the thermostat can "steal" power from the other wires but I have never seen this work as expected.
You have enough conductors in your wire to get everything running. If you could provide more detail on your setup maybe we can clarify more.

Is it normal for the furnace's W to not be connected, then?  If W is part of the heating circuit, I'd expect it to be needed at both ends.  Or maybe that's my problem in the first place.  || The thermostats had previously been working without a C - I'm guessing because it could steal from both R's, but (as you say) it doesn't really work with only one.    || Also, what other details would be useful?  I don't even know what might be helpful to know.

@Matthew Which photo shows that the common wire is not connected?

@DelphicOracle the C wire in the thermostat is not connected
